# To what extent can I make my C++/OpenGL project work on both iPad and PC?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, sdl

I'm developing a little game on Linux at the moment but I'd like to try making an iPad app out of it.

I've been looking over tutorials and it seems like I'll be able to make the my core C++ code compile on XCode without modification (it has no dependencies outside the standard library), and if I use OpenGL with SDL for the UI then the bulk of that code should be portable as well.

I assume that a certain amount of code will have to be different between the build processes, obviously I'd like to minimise that. I've never done any XCode development before, so can someone please advise on the following:

1. Will I be able to make the XCode project point to the core library source tree and compile it without dicking around with it, inserting project files etc? In other words, can I keep all XCode-specific files somewhere completely different? I use CMake on Linux and like would like to keep the out-of-tree build approach.
2. What at the SDL layer will have to be done differently for the iOS build? In other words, if I have a slave `libgraphics` library which is SDL and can paint the core state into a context provided by its master application, how do I create this context differently on iOS as compared to Linux?

At the moment I know nothing about the particulars of window creation and user input on iOS, or any Apple product caveats (e.g. how do I respond to the iPad going to sleep). I'd appreciate any pointers about all of this but the real question here is **how do I structure the project so as to be maximally cross-platform?**